# Can I do this in SPOnline/O365 - Manage limited resources

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have just introduced O365 and SP Online to the organisation.  I have a requirement to manage our fleet of electric cars and I think I should be able to do it in workflows and calendars.  The basic requirement is that a user should be able to reserve ONE car in advance (calendar), however they will not care WHICH of the 5 cars they have.
Effectively I have a resource type (Electric Car) and 5 instances of that resource (Car-A to Car-E).  I want the user to be able to check IF ONE of the resources is available and put in a reservation but not allocate it to a specific instance of that resource until I get closer to the date, then the specific resource will be allocated (normally the day before).  I will also need to be able to over-ride the availability of one or more instances of the resource-type as sometimes the cars need to be recharged or become out of action at very short notice (e.g. accident or not returned in time).
Is this kind of resource pooling possible directly in SPo or do I need to get more sophisticated and use Access Online (I would rather not!)

If it works for the cars I will be doing something similar for Projectors and Laptops!

Please note, I am only asking if this is possible before doing more research, but If someone has templates that I could 'research' from I would be very grateful :)

TIA

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Is this a public facing web application or an intranet(which requires the user to be on your organization's O365 subscription) ? If its going to be a internet/public facing website then SharePoint Online is not your best fit. Here is the official announcement made by Microsoft. Hope it helps

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3027254

Comment: This is for intranet use only

Comment: Then SP Online is the perfect fit I would say, you want me to build it for you :D JK

Comment: Not yet. I like to try to learn these things myself first.  But perhaps.  Give a man a fish and feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and ruin a perfectly valid business model :)

Comment: I agree, good luck :)